# espresso custom TestRunner with RxJava2 - using Rx2Idler getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-espresso, square

I have successfully created a custom espresso test runner which looks like this:

```
public class PomeloTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler(
                Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));

        RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));

        super.onCreate(arguments);
    }
}
```

my network layer of my application is written in rxjava2 so and I needed a way to link the espresso scheduling with rxjava so I chose to use [Rx2Idler](https://github.com/square/RxIdler)

but the problem I am getting is that when I run my tests I am getting the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
                                                   Process: com.mobile.pomelo.labs, PID: 11611
                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.support.test.espresso.IdlingResource$ResourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.squareup.rx2.idler.DelegatingIdlingResourceScheduler.stopWork(DelegatingIdlingResourceScheduler.java:96)
                                                       at com.squareup.rx2.idler.DelegatingIdlingResourceScheduler$ScheduledWork.run(DelegatingIdlingResourceScheduler.java:142)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
                                                       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

here is my actual test if it's of any importance. the test fails but if I remove the scheduler overrides it works with the sleep:

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)

public class AuthenticationActivityTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mIntentsTestRule.getActivity().sharedPrefRepo.clearAll();
    }


    @Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<AuthenticationActivity> mIntentsTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<AuthenticationActivity>(AuthenticationActivity.class) {
                @Override
                protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
                    Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
                            .getTargetContext();
                    Intent result = new Intent(targetContext, AuthenticationActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("action", AuthenticationActivity.LoginActions.LOGIN);

                    result.putExtras(b);
                    return result;
                }
            };



    @Test
    public void signupWithFacebook() {

        final Intent resultData = new Intent();
        resultData.putExtra("com.facebook.LoginFragment:Result", LoginClientCreator.createResult());
        intending(hasComponent(FacebookActivity.class.getName()))
                .respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData));

        // click signup fb button
        onView(withId(R.id.fb_login_button))
                .perform(click());

        // check facebook intent was hit
        intended(hasComponent(FacebookActivity.class.getName()), times(1));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(14000); // i dont want this to sleep,  i would rather the espresso idle sync work with rxjava2
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ViewInteraction appCompatTextView = onView(allOf(withText("COLLECTIONS"), isDisplayed()));
        appCompatTextView.perform(click());
    }
}
```

also take note that all my rxjava calls look like the following:

```
public void execute(@NonNull Observer UseCaseSubscriber){
                 this.buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber);
    }
```

update: i am wondering if its the firebase network calls which are not idle synced. these calls are not using rxjava so could they be not handled by Rx2Idler ?

Comment: Hello! Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried various options like setup RxJava plugins in `onCreate()` of Test Runner class, or registering ResourceCallback on all resources.

**But solution worked for me is just setting up RxJavaPlugins after           `super.onStart()`**

Please check code here:

```
public class AppTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        setupRxJavaPlugins();
    }

    private void setupRxJavaPlugins() {
        // rx-java 2
        RxJavaPlugins.setInitComputationSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Computation Scheduler"));

        RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x IO Scheduler"));

        RxJavaPlugins.setInitNewThreadSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x NewThread Scheduler"));

        RxJavaPlugins.setInitSingleSchedulerHandler(Rx2Idler.create("RxJava 2.x Single Scheduler"));

        // rx-java 1
        rx.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(RxIdler.hooks());
    }
}
```